# How to make Secure service to service calls between ASP.Net website and agent

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, azure, asp.net-web-api2

I have a ASP.Net WebAPI service that is used by my AngularJS front end and I am making use of Owin and bearer token.

Now there is a need that we need to install an agent on the few of the client machines (developed in .Net core mostly) that is able to connect to our application and make similar calls. I can create a separate controller for this need, but want to host it in the same website.

How can I create a secure connection between this agent and the ASP.Net server hosted on Azure?

Currently I am looking at generating a Token during the agent installation based on the client MAC address and giving it with each call, but I am checking if there are any better way to address this need.

Any help in this direction is welcome.

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you’d like to enable only valid “agents” that installed on the client machines to communicate with your server, if that is the case, Azure AD provides [Native Application to Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#native-application-to-web-api) authentication scenario (a native application that runs on a phone, tablet, or PC needs to authenticate a user to get resources from a web API that is secured by Azure AD), you could refer to it.

Comment: Thanks, I was specifically looking for https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless